# For loop issue with encryption script

Tags: python, encryption

I am trying to create a simple program to encrypt a string and return its encrypted characters.

However I am having an issue with the for loop which is causing Python to display the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/Uni/Programming/encrypt", line 18, in <module>
encrypt(encin)
File "C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/Uni/Programming/encrypt", line 12, in encrypt
encout += e6
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'encout' referenced before assignment
```

Here is the code:

```
key = 10
encout = ''
def encrypt(s):
    for c in s:
        if c != ' ' :
            e1 = ord(s)
            e2 = e1 - 97
            e3 = e2 + key
            e4 = e3 % 26
            e5 = e4 + 97
            e6 = chr(e5)
            encout = encout + e6
        else:
            encout = encout + c
a = input("To encrypt a string type 1, to decrypt a string type 2: ")
if a == '1':
    encin = input("Please type the string to encrypt: ")    
encrypt(encin)
print(encout)
```

Can you see any issues with it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message says, you're reading the value of `encout`, a local variable of the `encrypt` function, *before* declaring it (that is, before anything has been assigned to it).

Get rid of the `encout` global variable -- it's useless, and move the `encout = ''` line to the beginning of `encrypt`. Then, add `return encout` at the very end of `encrypt` (after the `for` loop terminates). Change the end of your program so that it reads:

```
print(encrypt(encin))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I will be using this as I prefer not to use 'global encout'.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're trying to do is:

```
e1 = ord(c)
```

You are iterating through the string's characters yet applying `ord` to the whole string (`s`) not the individual character `c`. This is the exception cause.

**UPDATE:** About the `encout` issue, you need to declare the variable on top of the method in order to access it before, like this:

```
def encrypt(s):
    encout = ''
    # remaining of the method
```

Comment: Thanks, that was dumb of me. I am now shown the error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'encout' referenced before assignment`

Comment: You're defining the `encout` variable outside a method and redefining it inside. That means problems with variable scope. Better make `encrypt` `return encout` and assign it to your global `encout` variable. Also, can you update the question with new info?